# delaying dragstart with jquery.event.drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, delay

I'm using `jquery.event.drag` to make an element drag. I would like to know how to delay the drag.

I tried:

```
$('#drag').bind('dragstart', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#drag').bind('drag', function(event) {
            $(this).css({
                top: event.offsetY,
                left: event.offsetX
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

But it's not working, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqDyw/
Is it possible to delay the element's drag? Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how I can get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, have you checked out jQueryUI's draggable plugin?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#delay-start

Pretty easy to implement your desired functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/hqDyw/1/

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to make it myself and then later implement it into the plugin i'm creating.